# MariaDB Crash Rolled back recovered transaction

Tags: mariadb, crash

For months my MariaDB is running fine but for the last 2 - 3 weeks it crashes randomly 2 - 3 times in the week.

i have observed the log files but i'm stuck for now. this is our main production server. i frustration at the moment. maybe some could help out

Server info:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
- MariaDB 10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
- Virtualmin 7.9

log:

```
2024-02-16  7:25:04 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 source revision  as process 4014

2024-02-16  7:25:03 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
2024-02-16  7:25:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 19930962113; transaction id 40459499
2024-02-16  7:25:03 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2024-02-16  7:25:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 240216  7:25:00
2024-02-16  7:25:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-02-16  7:25:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-02-16  7:25:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2024-02-16  7:25:00 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2024-02-16  8:13:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240216  8:13:06
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457346
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457459
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457382
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457350
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457230
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457326
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457183
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457368
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457159
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457556
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457340
2024-02-16  8:13:02 7 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-02-16  8:13:02 6 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457190
Version: '10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 22.04
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
2024-02-16  8:13:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 40457236
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.16 started; log sequence number 19927489307; transaction id 40457569
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of recovered transactions
2024-02-16  8:13:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-02-16  8:12:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: To recover: 9912 pages
2024-02-16  8:12:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 40457568
```

and

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_expire%';
+----------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name              | Value  |
+----------------------------+--------+
| binlog_expire_logs_seconds | 864000 |
+----------------------------+--------+
```

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_expire%';`

Comment: That log is not in chronological order??

Comment: @RickJames i've updated my post